# MVC Areas and Selective Deployment Strategies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, asp.net-mvc-areas

A general deployment related question for a project that uses MVC Areas. We built a MVC project with areas and each area is a module in a bigger application. Each module can be considered as a separate sub-application with its own specific function. The web application UI is designed such that there are different horizontal Picture/Icon tabs (nav bar), with each icon taking the user to that particular sub application/module. When we make code changes to a particular module (MVC area) and want to move those changes to QA or Production, we are now having to move the entire code base (including MVC areas we have not touched in the current iteration). Is there a way we can do selective deployment and move only changes that are necessary to QA or Prod without having to move other code ? Or do we have to re design and move away from Areas and maintain separate projects for each module ? The purpose of having areas is to have this modular structure in a large application, I am curious as to how people handle this aspect of deployment when the application is really big with lots of areas built into it.